# ASP.NET database connection closes when launching website

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, connection-string

I have decided to start programming in ASP.NET MVC using C#
I have been following tutorials and implementing them into my own project.

What happens is that once i click Debug in Chrome/Firefox etc my database connection closes (the red cross appears)! (But when I refresh it manually it has the tick - till that point) I have a feeling it's to do with the connectionString in web.config. I don't like connection strings, to me they seem full of jargon. How many parameters do you REALLY need for a test project?

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="PetsDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MainDBModel.csdl|res://*/MainDBModel.ssdl|res://*/MainDBModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|E:\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Pets\Pets\App_Data\PetsDB.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Unfortunately my knowledge of c#/asp.net mvc is VERY limited, hence following a tutorial but I know you guys at SO are really good at what you do.

The database named PetsDBEntities has the following properties.

Data Source: Microsoft SQL Server Database File (SQL Client)
Database File Name: projects/app_data/PetsDB.mdf

If i right click the database and click >Modify Connection and then click test connection I get a "This connection cannot be tested because the specified database file does not exist"

This is where the code breaks. NOTE: The values being submitted are passed through, it just seems that it is unable to connect and add the row to the database.

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    using( var db = new PetsDBEntities())
   {
        var crypto = new SimpleCrypto.PBKDF2();

        var encrpPass = crypto.Compute(user.Password);

        var regUser = db.Users.Create();

        regUser.Email = user.Email;
        regUser.Password = encrpPass;
        regUser.PasswordSalt = crypto.Salt;
        regUser.UserID = Guid.NewGuid();

        db.Users.Add(regUser);
        db.SaveChanges(); //--------THIS IS WHERE I GET AN ERROR---------

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Pictures");
    }
}
else
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login Data is incorrect!");
}

return View();
```

Hopefully this is enough information for you guys to spot where the problem is.
Thansk for anyone that can help! Again, I am new and not entirely sure what information is completely needed.

Comment: `LocalDB` is really just SQLExpress. Are you using Code First?

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is likely with the db filename.

```
attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|E:\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Pets\Pets\App_Data\PetsDB.mdf;
```

Should be:

```
attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\PetsDB.mdf;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) can help?

A simple connection string for SQL Server could be `Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;`

Comment: No; the OP is using Entity Framework, which requires some extra parameters in the connection string, so this won't work.

Comment: Well, in my defense, the question isn't tagged as Entity Framework, neither does it clearly states that Entity Framework is used. However, it clearly states that the data source is Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: `System.Data.EntityClient` is the provider for Entity Framework. The code included in the question is also (to anyone who normally uses it) obviously Entity Framework. Don't take this as an insult; just saying your suggestion won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that when you click on test connection, you are getting an error. Your question title might be misleading, as i can assume that you didn't established the connection at all.

Can you go to "Server Explorer" -> "Data Connections" -> "Add Connection" -> "Microsoft SQL Server Database File", i assume you are using the .mdf file directly instead of connecting to SQL server?

Click on "Test Connection" and if everything goes well, you can retrieve the connectionstring from the properties.